# Waterproofer Elastomeric Roof Sealant - sticky

Tags: roof, paint

I have a walk out terrace. I applied Waterproofer Elastomeric Roof Sealant (Henry). It looks great and its reflective. However, after 3 weeks its still sticky. Is it supposed to be sticky for that long?

The product is: #HE289146 (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Henry-0-90-Gal-289-Elastocaulk-Acrylic-Roof-Sealant-HE289146/100051524)

Comment: Henry makes a few different elastomeric roof coatings - could you identify exactly which one you have? Either the full name or the 3-digit number like 287, 587 or whatever it is, or just add a pic of the bucket.

Comment: Added more information. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the manufacturer's [product description](https://henry.com/commercial/commercial-mastics-and-cements/henry-289-white-roof-sealant/) & [datasheet](https://henry.com/fileadmin/pdf/current/tds/HE289_techdata.pdf) it appears that they intend for this product to have another coating applied on top - it's not intended as the only or final coating.

The product description reads:

> ... specially formulated for repairing and preventing roof leaks **prior to coating with an acrylic reflective coating**

and the datasheet has:

> ... and allow to set up **before coating**

So my interpretation of the problem is that you're supposed to coat this with something else to end up with a final (non-sticky) finish.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was beginning to worry. What would the final product be?

Comment: As noted in the quote above, @NinjaGaiden, "an acrylic reflective coating". I'm sure Henry's web site will list several options that will work well with the product you've purchased.